# continuity and limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I want to prove that if $f(x)$ has a limit for all natural numbers (to infinity), it doesn't necessary has a limit for a specific $x_0$ value.

To disprove, I came up with this function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x\in \ \mathbb{Q} \\
                     -1 &, x \in \ \mathbb{R\setminus Q}\end{cases}$$

so for all natural numbers the limit is $1$ because all natural numbers are rational but I'm not sure how to prove it or even if this is a right approach.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693277/real-analysis-limits-and-continuity-of-piecewise-function?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by it has a limit for all natural numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I have fully understood you but that function does not work. As $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ you can approach every natural number using just rational or irrational numbers. For what you seek, what about $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=[x+1/2]$ (floor function). In a neighbourhood of every natural number it is constant and at points with fractional part $1/2$ it has a jump.